# ¿Cómo transformar archivos en diccionarios de Python?

Tags: python

Necesito convertir este archivo `.dat` a un diccionario

```
1,casa,2,house,3,maison

2,table,3,table,1,mesa

3,fille,2,daughter,1,hija

2,she,1,ella,3,elle
```

He intentado resolverlo mediante un ciclo `for`, pero los números no me dejan trabajar.

```
{"español":["casa","mesa","hija","ella"],"ingles":["house","table","daughter","she"],"frances":["maison","table","fille","elle"]}
```

Comment: Deberías de añadir el código que has hecho hasta el momento. ¿El diccionario que adjuntas abajo, es el que obtienes o el que esperas?

Comment: es el diccionario que espero. mi codigo era un desastre y no funcionaba, pense que no aportaria nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El proceso es línea por línea del archivo de entrada.

Cada línea es dividida en palabras usando `split(",")`. Esto nos devuelve una lista donde alternan los números (indicando el idioma) y la palabra es esa idioma.

Cada vez que encontramos un identificador de idioma, lo guardamos. La siguiente palabra en la lista es la palabra a almacenar.

Para almacenar las palabras usamos un diccionario indexado por idioma ("español", "inglés", "frances"). Cada entrada contiene una lista, inicialmente vacia, de las palabras en ese idioma.

El diccionario es un `defaultdict`, que automáticamente crea las entradas cuando estas no existen. El argumento es el tipo de entrada a crear. En este caso, debe crear una lista vacía, así que usamos `defaultdict(list)`.

En el archivo de entrada los idiomas se identifican con un dígito 1-3, por lo que ocupamos el diccionario `key_dic` para convertir de número a texto (1 -> "español", ...)

```
from collections import defaultdict

key_dic = {"1": "español", "2": "inglés", "3":"frances"}
dic = defaultdict(list)
with open("datos.csv") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        for palabra in line.strip().split(","):
            if palabra.isnumeric():
                key = key_dic[palabra]
            else:
                dic[key].append(palabra)

for idioma in dic:
    print(idioma, ":", *dic[idioma])
```

produce

```
español : casa mesa hija ella
inglés : house table daughter she
frances : maison table fille elle
```